# Earthing or nothing

Tags: soft-question, electric-current

Sometimes, mostly in winter, when somebody touches the tap it passes current (especially when the hands are soaked in water or soap water). I read 3-4 years back in physics book that the tap circuit is connected to some copper plate which is dug inside the ground (called earthing). And then somebody suggested that if we don't touch the tap gently with fingers but like grab it with our hands (use all fingers), then you won't get current and surprisingly it did seem to work. Is it earthing and why does this current effect happen with tap... it doesn't happen anymore... but it was quite common to me in the past when I bathed. Is earthing and copper thing related to this? Copper thing seems quite far fetched and delusional, but can it be true? Or is there some other common system to get rid of this tap current in modern households?

Comment: Huh?  What is *commerce stream*, and how can you be "in" it.

Comment: It means I did not take any of the sciences(except maths) as my subjects... And rather took subjects related to commerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you feel the discharge when touching a conductive object after having picked up some static electricity.  This is common, and the object does not need to grounded.

Your body is a conductor, and as such has some capacitance to its surroundings.  When you shuffle accross a polyester carpet or something, this capacitor gets charged up.  Since the other side of the capacitor is largely connected to ground, touching a well grounded object,  like a metal water pipe dug into the ground, will provide a good discharge path.  Other sufficiently large objects will do too, but a grounded object will usually have a larger result because most of your capacitance is with respect to ground.

Grabbing a ground object hard with your hands doesn't change this at all.  What it does is provide so much other touch sensation that the zap feeling can get lost in the noise.  In other words, it doesn't reduce the discharge, only makes it less likely you will feel it by increasing noise and therefore decreasing the signal to noise ratio.

To not get zapped to the level you can feel it, you can discharge yourself slowly before touching a grounded object.  A good way to do this is to touch some object with high resistivity, but not so high that static charges don't bleed off after a few seconds.  A wooden door is often good for this.  Wood has high resistivity, but due to some inevitable moisture, it allows enough current to flow so that a static charge can't be maintained on it for very long.

As a experiment, find a way to reliably charge youself up.  This might be shuffling accross the right carpet with the right kind of socks on a dry day, for example.  Once you find a good method, you can reliably touch something grounded and feel a zap.  Now try touching that same object first thru a 10 MΩ resistor or something.  With a high enough resistance, the discharge current is so low that you can't feel it.  But, your body capacitor is still discharged, so when you then touch ground directly the charge is gone and there is no zap.

For example, if your body forms a 10 pF capacitor to ground and you discharge it thru a 10 MΩ resistor, the time constant is 100 µs, so you are still discharged instantly on a human scale.

Comment: Nice answer but I did not understand the technical jargon ( scientific words ),I am a layman . Thank you , sir.

Comment: @Inquist: What technical jargon?  What terms did I use you can't expect to see in high school physics or at the very least basic freshman physics in college?